# Sorting like excel in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have a column in a table whose values are,

```
a100,a7,a20,16,17,bbb,ccc,15kk,24dd
```

I want to sort this column and expected result (same like excel) is,

```
16,17,15kk,24dd,bbb,ccc,a7,a20,a100
```

i.e.:

Empty first then numeric then alpha-numeric then alphabetical then alphanumeric.
I have tried multiple solutions from google but all failed. Most of the solution are mixing numeric and alpha-numeric together like 15kk, 16, 17.

Comment: What's the difference between "then alpha-numeric" and "then alphanumeric"?

Comment: Its numeric-alpabet ie 15kk. Read it as numeric-alpabet instead of alpha-numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with data (nr) as (
  values ('a100'),('a7'),('a20'),('16'),('2'),('17'),('bbb'),('ccc'),('15kk'),('24dd')
)
select *
from data
order by case 
           when nr ~ '^[0-9]+$' then 1
           when nr ~ '^[0-9]+[a-z]+$' then 2
           when nr ~ '^[^0-9]+$' then 3
           when nr ~ '^[a-z]+[0-9]+' then 4
         end, 
         case 
           when nr ~ '^[0-9]+$' then nr::integer
           when nr ~ '^[0-9]+[a-z]+$' then regexp_replace(nr, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')::integer
           else 0
         end, 
         nr;
```

The above returns:

```
nr  
----
2   
16  
17  
15kk
24dd
bbb 
ccc 
a100
a20 
a7
```

The first case creates "groups" based on the structure of the value,

The second case makes sure that the "real" numbers are sorted according to their numeric values to make `'16'` sort after `'2'`.

And the final `nr` sorts the alphanumeric values inside the groups

Online example: http://rextester.com/JMG51196

Comment: This example fails if you have value like 4kkj56kj

Comment: @user2331417: I adjusted the `regexp_replace()`

Comment: but numeric alpha is sorting according to alpha instead of numeric for eg 7kkj56kj ,15kk, 24dd instead of 15kk, 24dd, 7kkj56kj